# Sorting of array of dictionary with date Swift 3

Tags: ios, arrays, sorting, swift3

I have an array called myArray in which dictionaries are added I want that dictionary to be sorted by time which is a key in dictionary. And that time is in String. The date format of time is "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"

I tried with below code solution but gives a warning of "Cast from 'String?' to unrelated type 'Date' always fails".

```
let sortedArray = self.myArray.sorted{ ($0["Time"] as? Date)! > ($1["Time"] as? Date)! }
print(sortedArray)
```

If anyone can help me out, Thank You.

Comment: Can you specify you time format?

Comment: I did that in question @Rahul

Comment: You can use `DateFormatter`

Comment: BTW, this idiom of yours `(v as? T)!` is quite funny ;-) Next time, you can simply do `v as! T` bro. I highly recommend taking the time to fully learn *Swift Optionals* — gonna help you a lot long term!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to convert to date time for this sort.  The international format (yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss) you're using provides the right sorting order as a string.

Comment: nice idea to compare:)

Comment: To make this clear, your code becomes `let sortedArray = self.myArray.sorted{ ($0["Time"])! > ($1["Time"])! }`

Answer (score 4):

You have to convert string into date using this code:

```
 let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2017/04/22 00:00:00") ?? Date()
```

So, use this:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"

    let sortedArray = self.myArray.sorted{[dateFormatter] one, two in
     return dateFormatter.date(from:one["Time"] )! > dateFormatter.date(from: two["Time"] )! }
```

Comment: No you don't need to convert the string to date in this case since the date strings are in a sortable format as-is.

Comment: FYI - the first bit of code you posted won't work since the string `22-04-2017 00:00:00` does not match the format specifier. The format specifier is correct, the sample date string is not.

Comment: @rmaddy I am getting "Binary operator '>' cannot be applied to two 'Any' operands" as I am having array of dictionary of type [String:Any]. in that case we have to convert date string into date..

Answer (score 1):

```
//Sort any dictionary with string dates using any date format
var incisions = [["initials": "B.B. ", "date": "12/18/17 09:39 AM", "patientID": "snowball"], ["patientID": "snowball", "date": "01/03/18 04:03 PM", "initials": "C.J."], ["initials": "B.B. ", "date": "01/04/18 09:47 AM", "patientID": "snowball"]]

func sortArrayDictDescending(dict: [Dictionary<String, String>], dateFormat: String) -> [Dictionary<String, String>] {
                let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                dateFormatter.dateFormat = dateFormat
                return dict.sorted{[dateFormatter] one, two in
                    return dateFormatter.date(from: one["date"]! )! > dateFormatter.date(from: two["date"]! )! }
            }

   //use:
let sortedArray = sortArrayDictDescending(dict: incisions, dateFormat: "MM/dd/yy a")

for i in sortedArray {
 print("incisions \(i["date"]!)")
}

//output:
incisions 01/04/18 09:47 AM
incisions 01/03/18 04:03 PM
incisions 12/18/17 09:39 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

simple code for sort an array of dictionary with date

```
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "MMM d, yyyy hh:mm a"
formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US")

let sorted = displayArray.sort {
    formatter.dateFromString($0["fullfireDate"] as! String)?.compare(formatter.dateFromString($1["fullfireDate"] as! String)!) != .OrderedAscending
    }
```